# Check permission; always a request against database?

Tags: performance, jsf, shiro

I have a question regarding Apache Shiro.
I´m using permission and role concept.

I have on the left side a menu with many links to my other pages (create an employee, show employee list etc.).
For each menu item I have also security for it to hide it or not (depends on the permission), like:

```
<pm:menu widgetVar="me"
rendered="#{checkPermissionController.checkPermission(['myprofile:show', 'myprofile:edit'])}">
```

To check if the user is permitted or not, I have those two functions in my bean:

```
/**
     * Check permission for login User
     * 
     * @return
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws PermissionGroupNotFoundException
     */
    public boolean checkPermission(String permissionName) throws IOException {

        if (loginBean.getCurrentUserShiro().isPermitted(permissionName)) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * If one of the permission is true
     * 
     * @param strings
     * @return
     */
    public boolean checkPermission(List<String> list) {

        int i = list.size();

        if (i != 0) {
            for (String s : list) {
                if (loginBean.getCurrentUserShiro().isPermitted(s)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

My question is now more against performance.
Is Apache Shiro execute for each menu entry a request against the database if the user is permitted or not?
Or does Shiro fetch at login time all permission for a user and "hold" it in the "Shiro User" object?

If yes: how can I improve it?

Edit:
Here my LoginBean:

```
@SessionScoped
@Named
public class LoginBean implements Serializable {

private Subject currentUserShiro;

public String submit() {

        LOGGER.info("START submit");

        try {

            currentUserShiro = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(username, password);
....
}

    ////////////////////
    // Getter + Setter
    ////////////////////
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public Subject getCurrentUserShiro() {
        return currentUserShiro;
    }
            currentUserShiro.login(token);
```

Comment: "Is Apache Shiro execute for each menu entry" - This strictly depends on the implementation of `getCurrentUserShiro()`. "If yes: how can I improve it?" - Use caching.

Comment: changed title: https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Comment: @Selaron is right, this programming problem would also show in a unittest...

Comment: I´ve updated the code... My bean is @SessionScoped.... What kind of caching do you mean? p:cache from primefaces? or caching in Shiro? which cache provider should I use?...

Comment: Or caching in  list/map in the session scoped bean... But yes, p:cache might help too (if you cache per user) And regarding _" Is Apache Shiro execute for each menu entry a request against the database if the user is permitted or not? Or does Shiro fetch at login time all permission for a user and "hold" it in the "Shiro User" object?"_ read the shiro manual or set some breakpoints or debug logging...

Comment: So you mean to store the permission in a java String list, like:
List<String> permissionList;
And my query is than if(permissionList.contains('user:create') ?

Comment: @Selaron: Can you explain a little bit more? It´s already @SessionBean?

Comment: It was not initially obvious that `getCurrentUserShiro()` returns a `Subject`. Next problem is that `Subject` is an interface and arbitrary implementations of `Subject` delegate the isPermitted() call to interfaces internally. I can't see which of those implementations are used by your runtime and if they are one that do caching. You'll have to debug step deeply into the `isPermitted` invocation and delegations. (This is what I'd do as I did not find documentation on that topic)

Comment: Ok, but is there no project or something else. I don´t think so, that I´m the only one that have this question?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using Shiro's filters to handle the actual login logic for you.
https://shiro.apache.org/web.html

Otherwise, you could end up with the Subject not tied to your Session. It looks like your application might be forcing a log in any time `getCurrentUserShiro` is called. You should let the framework handle this for you.

It's not a JSF, but you can see a basic JSP example here (the Shrio config logic will be the same):
https://github.com/apache/shiro/tree/master/samples/servlet-plugin

You would likely just replace the login page: https://github.com/apache/shiro/blob/master/samples/servlet-plugin/src/main/webapp/login.jsp with your custom page

Comment: I´m not sure what you mean.... I have already shiro.ini in my project? and I have also a login page. otherwise the user is not logged in....

Comment: Right, but you are still managing the authentication part directly, I'm suggesting you let Shiro handle that instead of manually calling subject.login()

Comment: I‘m not sure what you mean. How can I handle it without calling subject.login? I need a button in jsf page and this is calling also subject.login ?

Comment: Let your application be without any authentication authorization custom code. Now add shiro.ini and enter Shiro environment listener in web.xml. Let Shiro do all authentication code for you.

Comment: @MarcMeister, take a look at the example code that i pointed you to.  Just post to the same form and your user will be logged in.

Comment: @BrianDemers: If I search for an example, they did this also like me: https://github.com/danielmt/shiro-primefaces-example/blob/master/src/main/java/org/example/shiro/bean/security/ShiroLoginBean.java

Comment: I'd strongly suggest going with the approach the Shiro Project uses in it's examples if/when possible.  In general, the less code that you write that deals with a user's credentials the better ;)